# Optimization of the Python code using Numpy and Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following code working:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
colum1 = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05]
colum2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
colum3 = [0.85,0.80,0.80,0.80,0.85,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
colum4 = [1743.85, 1485.58, 1250.07, 1021.83, 818.96, 628.05, 455.40, 319.03, 190.86 , 97.07, 26.96 , 0.00]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colum1' : colum1,
    'colum2' : colum2,
    'colum3' : colum3,
    'colum4' : colum4,
});

df['result'] = 0
for i in range(len(colum2)):
    df['result'] = np.where(
        df['colum2'] <= 5,
        np.where(
            df['colum2'] == 1,
            df['colum4'],
            np.where(
                ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * (df['colum1'] * df['colum3'])) )>0,
                ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * (df['colum1'] * df['colum3'])) ),
                0
            )
        ),
        np.where(
            ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * df['colum1']) )>0,
            ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * df['colum1']) ),
            0
        )
    )
```

and I need to perform the same operation without resorting to a for cycle.
This would be very helpful, since I am working with thousands of records, which is very slow.

My expected result is the following:

```
    colum1  colum2  colum3   colum4       result
0     0.05       1    0.85  1743.85  1743.850000
1     0.05       2    0.80  1485.58  1415.826000
2     0.05       3    0.80  1250.07  1193.436960
3     0.05       4    0.80  1021.83   974.092522
4     0.05       5    0.85   818.96   777.561068
5     0.05       6    0.00   628.05   589.171947
6     0.05       7    0.00   455.40   425.941403
7     0.05       8    0.00   319.03   297.732930
8     0.05       9    0.00   190.86   175.973354
9     0.05      10    0.00    97.07    88.271332
10    0.05      11    0.00    26.96    22.546433
11    0.05      12    0.00     0.00     0.000000
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop in the first place? Seems like the code will work if you just remove it and bring the loop body to an outer level of indentation.

Comment: The biggest problem is in the .shift(1) :(

Comment: How confident are you in your expected result, I can only reproduce the first several rows, then they vary

Comment: @user3483203 sorry, I just corrected

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to remove the loop over the index and replace those tests for numbers greater than 0 with [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html). This works because `np.where(a > 0, a, 0)` for our purposes is equivalent to `np.maximum(0, a)`.

At the same time define the longer expressions separately to make your code readable:

```
s1 = df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * (df['colum1'] * df['colum3']))
s2 = df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * df['colum1'])

df['result'] = np.where(df['colum2'] <= 5,
                        np.where(df['colum2'] == 1, df['colum4'],
                                 np.maximum(0, s1)),
                        np.maximum(0, s2))
```

The next step is to use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to remove the nested `np.where` statements:

```
m1 = df['colum2'] <= 5
m2 = df['colum2'] == 1

conds = [m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2]
choices = [df['colum4'], np.maximum(0, s1)]

df['result'] = np.select(conds, choices, np.maximum(0, s2))
```

This version will be more manageable.

Comment: thanks, it is a more manageable version, but it does not solve my intention to eliminate the buble for to obtain the desired result.

Comment: The last solution has no explicit `for` loop, isn't that what you want?

Comment: I just edit the question adding the desired result, but delete the buble the resutlado is different

Comment: SO isn't (just) a code writing service. I'm happy to clarify **logic, concepts, performance** type queries if you have any. But "get these numbers" in itself is not something either I, or other users, will find interesting.