# Vectorization of loops in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
colum1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
colum2 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colum1' : colum1,
    'colum2' : colum2
});

df.loc[df.colum1 == 1,'result'] = df['colum2']

for i in range(len(colum2)):
    df.result = np.where(df.colum1>1, 5 - (df['colum2'] - df.result.shift(1)), df.result)
```

the result of df.result is:

```
    colum1  colum2  result
0        1      10    10.0
1        2      20    -5.0
2        3      30   -30.0
3        4      40   -65.0
4        5      50  -110.0
5        6      60  -165.0
6        7      70  -230.0
7        8      80  -305.0
8        9      90  -390.0
9       10     100  -485.0
10      11     110  -590.0
11      12     120  -705.0
```

I would like to know if there is a method that allows me to obtain the same result without using a cycle for

Comment: Care to describe in words what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to avoid the use of cycles, vectorize the code.

Comment: I understand that, I mean can you explain what the *code* is trying to *do*.

Comment: @Parfait but he uses the result of the last iteration.  The results are *not* the same.  What you've suggested will produce only the first two values correctly

Comment: Something similar to this:
`df.result = np.where (df.colum1> 1, 5 - (df ['colum2'] - df.result.shift (1) .cumsum ()), df.result)`
     Since I'm working with thousands of records, which is very slow

Comment: @Parfait, The results are not the same

Comment: @user3483203 ... I literally copied OP's post without change and ran above line resulting in `df['result'] == df['result2']` in all rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's because you already have the result of `df.result` in your dataframe (which is used in the `np.where`.  Your code does not work, you are simply copying over the given output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operation is dependent on two things, the previous row in the DataFrame, and the difference between consecutive values in the DataFrame.  That hints that the solution will require `shift` and `diff`.  However, you want to add a small constant to the expanding sum, as well as actually subtract this from each row, not add it.

---

To set the pieces of the problem up, first create your shifted series, where you add `5`:

```
a = df.colum2.shift().add(5).cumsum().fillna(0)
```

Now you need the difference between elements in the Series, and fill missing results with their respective value in `colum2`:

```
b = df.colum2.diff().fillna(df.colum2)
```

To get your final result, simply subtract `a` from `b`:

```
b - a
```

```
0      10.0
1      -5.0
2     -30.0
3     -65.0
4    -110.0
5    -165.0
6    -230.0
7    -305.0
8    -390.0
9    -485.0
10   -590.0
11   -705.0
Name: colum2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect, could you help me with this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730328/optimization-of-the-python-code-using-numpy-and-pandas), thanks!

Comment: @YeisonH.Arias what exactly do you need help with, it looks like you already have an answer that vectorizes the operation

Comment: for the question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730328/optimization-of-the-python-code-using-numpy-and-pandas) the answer given does not work, the result is erroneous  :/

Comment: I appreciate you if you can help me with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730328/optimization-of-the-python-code-using-numpy-and-pandas), I have already updated the desired result, thanks!